# OpenCV detect which pins are bent

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this image of a pin header, and I need to detect if there are bent pins in the header using OpenCV.

[image]

### UPDATE, solved

Thanks to Nick, I have made something that works pretty good, not prefect but oke!

I use the `findContours` function to find all contours. Then I loop over all the items and find the `minAreaRect`, and draw a box of the given size. When a box has a width greaten then a set threshold the pin is too bend (out of spec).

```cpp
for (const auto &entry: fs::directory_iterator(SAMPLES)) {
    try {
        // Load src image
        src = imread(entry.path(), IMREAD_COLOR);
        // Blur
        medianBlur(src, blurred, 3);
        // Set threshold
        threshold(blurred, blurred, 100, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

        // Edge detection
        Canny(blurred, detected_edges, thres1, thres2, 3);
//            imshow("blurred", blurred);

        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        // Find all the contours in the image
        findContours(detected_edges, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        vector<RotatedRect> minRect(contours.size());
        vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
        vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());

        int bendPins = 0;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
            // bind all shapes to the vectors
            minRect[i] = minAreaRect(contours[i]);
            approxPolyDP(contours[i], contours_poly[i], 3, true);
            boundRect[i] = boundingRect(contours_poly[i]);

            // Draw the min area rect need to fill the contour
            Rect rect(boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br());
            rectangle(src, rect, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);

            // When a pin it to bend
            if (rect.width > threshold_bend) {
                Point centerRect = (boundRect[i].br() + boundRect[i].tl()) * 0.5;
                circle(src, centerRect, 20, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2);
                bendPins++;
            }

            // Draw a rect around the pin, bent or not
            Point2f rect_points[4];
            minRect[i].points(rect_points);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                line(src, rect_points[j], rect_points[(j + 1) % 4], Scalar(0, 255, 255), 1);
            }
        }

        char buffer[100];
        snprintf(buffer, 100, "Found bend pin(s) : %d", bendPins);
        putText(src, buffer, Point(10, 25), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);

        imshow(entry.path().filename(), src);

        waitKey();

    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

The result:
[image: output]

Comment: It is hard to comment on something that works. You should rather run your algorithm on different pictures of your use case to see when it fails and ask about the fails then.

Comment: I can only detect some edges.. that's all, but I want to check if the pins are bent. My code now does not tell me that.

Comment: As you named it, a threshold on the angle would achieve this fine in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [cv::findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html).

You should be able to extract the pins with that, maybe binarize first with cv::threshold(). Then using [center-of-mass](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) and the moment-of-area for the contours found, you can describe the position and angle of the pins. Or just using the bounding rectangle might even be enough.

Comment: @StefandeKraker: OK, great ! If you still need to refine this (you said it only works most of the time), using the Rotated Rectangles rotation against against some threshold might do that. Also check that the size for broken pins. Some tuning requierd, as usual in machine vision :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach with code and results.

Steps to produce:

**(preprocessing)**

1. Apply median to decrease noise in the image
2. Apply threshold to get a clear image

**Here is the result of these 2 steps:**

[image]

3. Check each row and get the sticks according to the thickness threshold.

**Result image of this step:**

[image]

4. Get mid point's y axis values of each stick and hold in an array.
5. Calculate the standard deviation of each array and choose the ones which are higher.

**Here is the code:**

```
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn_superres.hpp>
#include <numeric>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/mean.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/moment.hpp>
using namespace boost::accumulators;
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

double stddev(std::vector<int> const & func)
{
    double mean = std::accumulate(func.begin(), func.end(), 0.0) / func.size();
    double sq_sum = std::inner_product(func.begin(), func.end(), func.begin(), 0.0,
        [](double const & x, double const & y) { return x + y; },
        [mean](double const & x, double const & y) { return (x - mean)*(y - mean); });
    return std::sqrt(sq_sum / func.size());
}


int main(){

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("/home/yns/Downloads/aaa.jpg",cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    cv::namedWindow("input",0);
    cv::namedWindow("output",0);
    cv::namedWindow("output2",0);

    cv::imshow("input",img);


    cv::Mat out;

    cv::medianBlur(img,img,3);

    cv::threshold(img,out,80,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    cv::Mat out2;

    cv::cvtColor(out,out2,cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);


    cv::imshow("output",out);

    int start = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    int refX = 0;
    int thresholdThickness = 5;

    int orderNum = 1;

    std::vector<int> yAxis_1;
    std::vector<int> yAxis_2;
    std::vector<int> yAxis_3;
    std::vector<int> yAxis_4;
    std::vector<int> yAxis_5;
    std::vector<int> yAxis_6;
    std::vector<int> yAxis_7;
    std::vector<int> yAxis_8;
    std::vector<int> yAxis_9;
    std::vector<int> yAxis_10;
    std::vector<int> yAxis_11;
    std::vector<int> yAxis_12;


    int annen = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<out.rows; i++)
    {
        orderNum = 1;
        annen = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<out.cols; j++)
        {

            if(out.at<uchar>(cv::Point(j,i))==255 && start != 1)
            {
                start = 1;
                refX = j;
                cnt = 0;
            }
            else if (out.at<uchar>(cv::Point(j,i))==255)
            {
                cnt++;
            }
            else if (out.at<uchar>(cv::Point(j,i))==0 && start == 1 && cnt>thresholdThickness) {
                cv::circle(out2,cv::Point((j+refX)/2,i),1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),cv::FILLED);
                start = 0;
                annen++;
                if(orderNum == 1)
                    yAxis_1.push_back(j);
                if(orderNum == 2)
                    yAxis_2.push_back(j);
                if(orderNum == 3)
                    yAxis_3.push_back(j);
                if(orderNum == 4)
                    yAxis_4.push_back(j);
                if(orderNum == 5)
                    yAxis_5.push_back(j);
                if(orderNum == 6)
                    yAxis_6.push_back(j);
                if(orderNum == 7)
                    yAxis_7.push_back(j);
                if(orderNum == 8)
                    yAxis_8.push_back(j);
                if(orderNum == 9)
                    yAxis_9.push_back(j);
                if(orderNum == 10)
                    yAxis_10.push_back(j);
                if(orderNum == 11)
                    yAxis_11.push_back(j);
                if(orderNum == 12)
                    yAxis_12.push_back(j);

                orderNum++;

            }
            else if (out.at<uchar>(cv::Point(j,i))==0 && start == 1)
            {
                start = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    std::cout<<stddev(yAxis_1)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<stddev(yAxis_2)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<stddev(yAxis_3)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<stddev(yAxis_4)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<stddev(yAxis_5)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<stddev(yAxis_6)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<stddev(yAxis_7)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<stddev(yAxis_8)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<stddev(yAxis_9)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<stddev(yAxis_10)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<stddev(yAxis_11)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<stddev(yAxis_12)<<std::endl;


    float average = accumulate( yAxis_6.begin(), yAxis_6.end(), 0.0)/yAxis_6.size();
    float average2 = accumulate( yAxis_7.begin(), yAxis_7.end(), 0.0)/yAxis_7.size();

    cv::circle(out2,cv::Point(average,out2.rows/2),25,cv::Scalar(0,255,255),5);
    cv::circle(out2,cv::Point(average2,out2.rows/2),25,cv::Scalar(0,255,255),5);




    cv::imshow("output2",out2);

    cv::waitKey(0);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Might want to put the yAxis-values in a vector<vector<>> to compress this. And could you comment the code some ?